# Visual Studio team services build solution from multiple repositories

Tags: .net, azure-devops

Hi we have solution which have projects in multiple repositories (they must be cloned in one folder) is there way to build it in Visual Studio Team Services?

Comment: Which version control are you using? Git or TFVC?

Comment: Given that you mention "clone" I suspect that you're using Git. The only way to do this is to create a repository that uses Git SubModules. Then trigger the build from there and have the submodules restored as part of the build.